# Ошибка в обратной связи

Tags: php

Добрый вечер .Написал обратную связь для сайта. Суть в ней что она отсылает почту пользователя и некоторую сумму мне на почту. Не понятно в том что если пользователь напишет любую почту на mail то не отправится сообщение мне на почту, а gmail и yandex приходят.

Форма связи

```
<div id="withdraw">';
<form id="f1" action=" withdraw.php" method="POST" name=" f1 ">';      
<input name="email" type="email" id="f1Email" maxlength="40" placeholder="Ваш  E-mail"  required/><br />';
<input name="value" type="number" min="10" id="f1Value" maxlength="20" placeholder="Введите сумму в кредитах"required /><br />';
<button id="withdrawbutt" type="submit" form="f1">Вывести</button>';
</form></div>';
```

php обработчик

```
<?php 
if(@$_POST['value'] == "" || @$_POST['email'] == "")
{
echo "<script>location.href='index.php';</script>";
}
else
{
$sendto   = "test@gmail.com"; // почта, на которую будет приходить письмо
$uservalue = $_POST['value']; 
$usermail = $_POST['email']; 

$date = date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A');

 // Формирование заголовка письма
$subject  = "Новое сообщение";
$headers  = "From: " . strip_tags($usermail) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags($usermail) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8 \r\n";

// Формирование тела письма
$msg  = "<html><body style='font-family:Arial,sans-serif;'>";
$msg .= "<h2 style='font-weight:bold;border-bottom:1px dotted     #ccc;'>Cообщение с сайта</h2>\r\n";
$msg .= "<p><strong>Почта игрока:</strong> ".$usermail."</p>\r\n";
$msg .= "<p><strong>Сумма :</strong> ".$uservalue."</p>\r\n";
$msg .= "<p><strong>Дата вывода:</strong> ".$date."</p>\r\n";
$msg .= "</body></html>";

// отправка сообщения
mail($sendto, $subject, $msg, $headers); 
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

У Вас беда с полем `from` . В нем должен стоять почтовый адрес, с которого Вы имеете право отправлять почту со своего сервера. Укажите в нем доменной почтовый ящик своего сервера, а e-mail пользователя отправляйте в теле письма, для информации. У mail.ru стала строгая политика `DMARC`.